# VBA formula to generate set of numbers

Tags: vba, ms-access

Background information.

I have a custom slider which I have constructed using an access form and some controls. It’s set to increment 1 to 40,

What I need.

VBA function which has the values below stored in an ARRAY and then when i move the slider 1 through 40 the corresponding number is called.

```
0.10
0.12
0.14
0.16
0.18
0.21
0.24
0.27
0.30
0.33
0.37
0.41
0.46
0.51
0.56
0.62
0.68
0.75
0.83
0.91
1.00
1.10
1.21
1.33
1.47
1.62
1.79
1.98
2.19
2.43
2.70
3.01
3.36
3.76
4.23
4.78
5.43
6.21
7.14
8.28
9.70
```

Comment: Um, insert them into a table?

Comment: Andre i do need the formula to generate them using code. thank you though.

Comment: Well, then use the `Array()` function - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Andre i get error type mismatch . if you know how to do it could you post example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what could go wrong, but here you are:

```
Public Function GetSliderNumber(ByVal i As Long) As Double

    Dim arNumbers As Variant

    arNumbers = Array(0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.21, 0.24)

    ' Array is zero-based, we want 1-based index
    i = i - 1
    ' Check we are inside array boundaries
    If i >= LBound(arNumbers) And i <= UBound(arNumbers) Then
        GetSliderNumber = arNumbers(i)
    Else
        ' or error message
        GetSliderNumber = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Direct window (Ctrl+g):

```
? GetSliderNumber(1), GetSliderNumber(5), GetSliderNumber(100)
 0,1           0,18          0
```

Comment: Might have been the ByVal but something wasn’t right because your code works and mine didn’t. Thank you very much for stirring me in the right direction and providing a viable solution. Thanks again.